# How to add aspects to hadoop 2.2

Tags: java, hadoop, aspectj, hadoop-yarn

I am on Linux, and I don't see the a jar file for aspectj, so I am curious how do I add aspects to yarn.  Ideally I would like to just use the Fault Injection Framework (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/FaultInjectFramework.html), but I am not certain if there is some way in the binaries to do this, or do I need to add it manually.

I am trying to make a change to the source code and I want to see which methods are called before I try to make my change, so I want to use `cflow` (http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/AspectJ+CFlowExplained) inside yarn.

Comment: This one is pretty old and probably no longer of interest to you, but if you still like to have an answer and can provide some sample code - ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - to illustrate your problem and the desired outcome, I might be able to suggest something.